# Azure importing data SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-dsvm

I've been trying to sort through Microsoft's extensive documentation, but, cannot find the answer I'm looking for, hence, posting it here for the experts!

I have a table in a database in MS SQL Server 2016, that I read/write to using MS SSMMS. I would like to export this single table into my Azure storage account for further analysis in the MS Data Science Virtual Machine, but cannot find a way to do this. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming that this tool works with flat files, the simplest solution is to run a select, copy/paste the results into notepad, then copy that file into your azure storage (using, for example Azure storage explorer)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use tools built into the MS Data Science Virtual Machine (DSVM) to first export from SQL Server to CSV. BCP (command line) is one tool.

If you want a graphic tool, use SSMS and use the "import and export" option to save result of your query to CSV file. Then you can copy the CSV file to a Azure storage account using Azcopy (command line) or Azure Storage explorer (graphical) also available on the DSVM. Hope this helps.